# How to create a file containing path and import that file into another python file in the so that the path does not need to be explicitly mentioed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wamp

I want to have a file which contains the path variable (my system's python path here will be F:/Python/python.exe) which is mentioned on the top of every python file stored in the www folder of wamp in Windows. Then I want to import that file to all the other files so that I don't need to mention the path on top of the file every time. Is this possible?

I have tried creating a function and creating a variable that stored the variable but obviously that can't be done. So how to create such a file which can be imported in other files. Or is there any other solution for what I want to achieve?

Comment: If you’re trying to edit `sys.path`, don’t—use a shell/batch script to launch your program with whatever desired `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Assuming you have a file `mymod.py` with `mypath = "some_path"`, you can get my path imported with `from mymod import mypath` and you can then refer to it as `mymod` in your other scripts(s), but I am not 100% I am clear on the problem description (and hence this may or may not be what you are looking for).

Comment: Just set PYTHONPATH in the environment for your web server.

Answer (score 0):

*You can try this way* 
Maybe this can help you to solve the problem

- Create a file main.py
- In that particular file do all the import statements

This will reduce the repentance of the import statements

**From your file:**
from main import *

Comment: But how to import the path in any of the file? How can I have a variable of path or any function which can be imported anywhere?

Comment: @Adwait_07 you can use this library `import sys` and you can use this library `import lib`